# posting multidimensional array from checkbox

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I have seen a couple of questions regarding posting arrays from checkboxes, however I havent seen anything attempting to do what I want to do.

I have a list of checkboxes that submit data populated in foreach loop of data from a database.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="phonelist[]" value="<?=strtoupper($device['id']);?>"/>
```

This is how I am currently returning multiple items for the checkbox phone list. Howver is it possible to add another value in the same value  section of the checkbox but under a different item in a multidimensional array?
e.g

```
<input type="checkbox" name="phonelist[][]" value="<?=strtoupper($device['id']);?><?=strtoupper($device['another value']);?>"/>
```

Im aware my "Psuedocode" is wrong but I hope it gets across the idea I wish to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you better approach it this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="phonelist[<?=strtoupper($device['id']);?>]" value="<?=strtoupper($device['id']);?>"/>
```

then

```
<input type="checkbox" name="phonelist[<?=strtoupper($device['id']);?>][<?=strtoupper($device['another value']);?>]" value="<?=strtoupper($device['id']).strtoupper($device['another value']);?>"/>
```

So you can still `foreach` `$_POST['phonelist']` but keep a reference value.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, add id for each section:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="phonelist[0][]" value="<?=strtoupper($device['id']);?><?=strtoupper($device['another value']);?>"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="phonelist[0][]" value="<?=strtoupper($device['id']);?><?=strtoupper($device['another value']);?>"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="phonelist[1][]" value="<?=strtoupper($device['id']);?><?=strtoupper($device['another value']);?>"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="phonelist[1][]" value="<?=strtoupper($device['id']);?><?=strtoupper($device['another value']);?>"/>
```

Comment: Adding ids for first subscript should be sufficient. Starting from 0 might be a good idea too.