# Foreach two array (php)

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to store the 2 array values in single row. However, I got unexpected output which return extra row in the datatable.

My php:

```
 $checkbox1=$_POST['name'];
        $checkbox2=$_POST['id'];        
           foreach ($checkbox1 as $pop )  
                {
                   $addsql = "insert into referral () values ('$pop','{$_POST['id']}')";
                   $addresult = mysql_query($addsql, $link);    
                }
```

My table (ERROR):

```
Name   ID
Alex   Array
1      Array
Alice  Array
2      Array
```

Expected Result:

```
Name   ID
Alex   1
Alice  2
```

Comment: can you try changing {$_POST['id']} to $checkbox2 in your insert statement

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php; you’re vulnerable to SQL injection and you should fix that before moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this work!

```
$checkbox1=$_POST['name'];
$checkbox2=$_POST['id'];
foreach ($checkbox1 as $k=>$pop){
    $addsql = "insert into referral () values ('$pop','$checkbox2[$k]')";
    $addresult = mysql_query($addsql, $link);    
}
```

Comment: why my ID records all missing, when i check the checkbox start from the middle row.

Comment: simple way to make a post with different value but same type on a checkbox you can use **multidimension** like `<input type='checkbox' name='name[1]' value='Alex'> Alex 1 <br> <input type='checkbox' name='name[2]' value='Alice2'> Alice 2` after that try to `print_r($_POST);` .. the result must be array..

Comment: check this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493440/posting-multidimensional-array-from-checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493440/posting-multidimensional-array-from-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` to prevent hijacking...

Use instead `$checkbox2` of `'{$_POST['id']}'`

Modify your code to

```
$checkbox1=$_POST['name'];
        $checkbox2=$_POST['id'];        
           foreach ($checkbox1 as $pop )  
                {
                   $addsql = "insert into referral () values ('$pop','$checkbox2')";
                   $addresult = $mysqli->query($addsql, $link);    
                }
```